# Spring data mongodb repository. How can I search by a list of IDs?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following class!

```
public class Task{
    ObjectId id;
    String title;
    String description;

    /* Getters and Setters removed for brevity */
}
```

and I have the following mongoRepository class, very simple :

```
public interface TaskRepository extends MongoRepository<Task, String> {

}
```

As you can see, I have not yet tried to extend this class - What would I want to do here if I want to have a find method, where I could just hand it a list of Ids, and get my list of corresponding tasks back?

Comment: `@Query("{ '_id': '$in': ?0 }')` on the appropriate `findBy` method? Don't have a mongoreposity based project handy ATM, but that you give you a good place to start looking.

Comment: Damn, I tried something exactly like this and was having trouble getting it working. Good to know I am on the right path though I guess.

Comment: Refer http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial and https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/baeldung/repository/UserRepository.java for more details

Comment: @NeilLunn, I tried your approach, but the generated statement contains the first `id` only: 
`find using query: { "_id" : { "$in" : [{ "$oid" : "5f9c88676b7c1372fc31474f"}]}} fields: Document{{logo=0}}`
`findAllById` is not an option for me, because I want to select certain fields only and not the whole document.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I found what was wrong in my query: `"{ '_id' : {'$in' : [?0] } }"`. I have to omit the brackets: `[ ]`. Correct: `"{ '_id' : {'$in' : ?0 } }"`

Answer (score 6):

The `CrudRepository` which `MongoRepository` extends has a [`findAll`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/1.14.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.java#L78) method, which takes an `Itereable<ID>`

I think that is exactly what you are looking for.

Note that it is renamed to [`findAllById`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.java#L78) in the latest Milestone releases.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom query method that searches for an array of `_id` values:

```
  @Query(value = "{ '_id' : {'$in' : ?0 } }", fields = "{ 'description': 0 }")
  Iterable<Task> findAllThin(Iterable<String> ids);
```

(in this case it returns the fields `id` and `title` only)

@Neil Lunn brought me to the answer.